# dygraph floating points for x-axis values

Tags: dygraphs

I'm not able to make dygraph plotting a graph with my data. The data consists of ~16,000 sets, but it doesn't work with just a couple of points either.

Example of data:

```
WL;Part1;Part2
187,3284416;-1748,493056;-1840,460648
187,3555635;-1884,175926;-1940,453704
187,382693;-1998,740741;-2017,085648
187,40983;-2143,993056;-2090,243056
187,4369744;-1977,905093;-1956,724537
187,4641264;-2019,69213;-1901,358796
```

My code so far:

```
  g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
    "data.csv", 
    {delimiter:';',
     xValueParser: parseFloat}
  );
```

If I change the data points of the X-axis as follows, I get a nice graph:

```
WL;Part1;Part2
187,3284416;-1748,493056;-1840,460648
188,3555635;-1884,175926;-1940,453704
189,382693;-1998,740741;-2017,085648
190,40983;-2143,993056;-2090,243056
191,4369744;-1977,905093;-1956,724537
192,4641264;-2019,69213;-1901,358796
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't help me because the points have to be like in the first example. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

It will work if you use points instead of commas for your decimals:

```
WL;Part1;Part2
187.3284416;-1748.493056;-1840.460648
187.3555635;-1884.175926;-1940.453704
187.382693;-1998.740741;-2017.085648
187.40983;-2143.993056;-2090.243056
187.4369744;-1977.905093;-1956.724537
187.4641264;-2019.69213;-1901.358796
```

[image: Graph with decimal points on X axis]

You'll see that the X axis labels have gone a bit crazy, but you can use the `axisLabelFormatter` options to get that under control - or maybe it will be fine once you've put in your whole dataset.

Comment: Stupid of me, I had missed that. Thank you!